# Node Js not running in Docker Environment Pin

Tags: node.js, express, docker

My NodeJS is not running in Docker environment. Specifically, my `express` module is not loaded within the Docker container.

This is my setup so far:

**server.js**

```
var express = require('express')

var app = express();

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    res.end('Hello world');
})

var server = app.listen(9005, function () {
    var host = server.address().address
    var port = server.address().port

    console.log("Example app listening at http://%s:%s", host, port)
})
```

**Dockerfile**

```
 FROM stefanscherer/node-windows:7.6.0-nano

 # Create app directory
 RUN mkdir -p /app
 WORKDIR /app

 # Install app dependencies
 COPY package.json /app/
 RUN npm install

 # Bundle app source
 COPY . /app

CMD ["node","server.js"]
EXPOSE 9005
```

Comment: Your problem statement is too broad could you provide more detail viz: If there is some error message or something like that.

Comment: Move the installation of your dependencies after you copied the source code and maybe you also need to do `RUN cd /app; npm install` instead of `RUN npm install`.

Comment: Are you sure the base image you are using exists ? From [repo tags](https://hub.docker.com/r/stefanscherer/node-windows/tags/) there seems to be only `8.x` and `6.x` versions.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you have included express in the dependencies section of package.json?